# Problems with google dart http client

Tags: httpclient, dart

So I upgraded my IDE and SDK and now the following code doesn't work anymore.  I am adding some text here to try to get around this sites fascist validation on posts it's pretty aggressive.

```
String URL = "http://www.google.com";
Future future = client.getUrl(Uri.parse(URL))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
        return request.close();
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
        print('Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
        print('Headers\n${response.headers}');
    });
});
```

I am getting the following exception now.

```
Uncaught Error: Bad state: No elements
Stack Trace:
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me using Dart `0.6.3.3_r24898` on Windows.

Are you sure this is all the code you have? In the stack trace I see `WebSocketImpl`, are you using WebSockets?

Comment: You right it's a websocket problem must be because of the new zone probably always been generating an error just never knew it ha.